# Jenkins grouping of nodes via label on demand

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy

I have a scenario where I have N numbers of nodes and N number of tests, and these tests will be distributed to the nodes. My nodes have a label `Windows`.

Here's an example:

I have a pipeline job that will manage the distribution of the tests to the nodes. I set my pipeline job to run 10 tests on 10 VMs having the label `Windows` and it will run smoothly. However, one of my requirements is to concurrently run that pipeline job. The problem I might encounter If I have 10 tests on VMs 1-10 in the first run of the job, and run another job for 5 tests for VMs 11-15, given that I am using the `Windows` label, there might be a possibility that Jenkins will assign the test to VMs 1-10 but should run on VMs 11-15 or vice versa.

The solution I came up with is to dynamically change the label of the VMs from one of the jobs to a unique label that will only be used for that Job. Unfortunately, I still don't know how to do that.

Basically, I just want to logically group my nodes via label on demand in my pipeline script.

I searched all throughout the internet and yet I still wasn't able to find a solution that fits my needs.

Kindly help me with this. Also, I am open to using a different approach.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50830619/2047614

Comment: Please this link will help you as it is parameter based label to execute node https://github.com/jenkinsci/nodelabelparameter-plugin

Comment: Hello @MaratC and prasad, I appreciate your help. Both of your answers are not the one I'm looking for. I already found what I need from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56207343/jenkins-groovy-update-the-labels-in-all-nodes). Thanks!